# I'm trying to call a function inside of a token loop in C. I keep segfaulting?

Tags: c, c-strings, strtok, function-definition, strcpy

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void pigLatinConsonant(char input[]) {
    char end[] = "ay";
    int length = strlen(input);
    int first_vowel = -1;
   
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (strchr("aeiou", input[i])) {
            first_vowel = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (first_vowel != -1) {
        char consonant_cluster[length + 1];
        strncpy(consonant_cluster, input, first_vowel);
        consonant_cluster[first_vowel] = '\0';

        strcpy(input, input + first_vowel);
        strcat(input, consonant_cluster);
    }

    strcat(input, end);
    printf("Translated word: %s\n", input);
}

int main() {
    char sentence[100];
    printf("Enter a sentence: ");

    fgets(sentence, sizeof(sentence), stdin);

    char sentence_copy[sizeof(sentence)];
    strcpy(sentence_copy, sentence);

    char *token = strtok(sentence_copy, " ");

    while (token != NULL) {
        pigLatinConsonant(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here I tried to call this method from the loop but I think it has something to do with how my function is built. The user enters a sentence, it should move the first two characters, and put them at the end of the word and add `ay` to it.

Comment: Have you tried to use a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to catch the crash, and see when and where in your code it happens?

Comment: It was stuck in the method. Atleast thats what i got from it? I found that when it segfaults, it simply repeats the end string? How is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

For starters your code has nothing common with the assignment

> The user enters a sentence, **it should move the first two characters,
> and put them at the end of the word and add 'ay' to it**.

This statement

```
strcpy(input, input + first_vowel);
```

already invokes undefined behavior.

You may not use `strcpy` when ranges are overlapping.

Instead you should use `memmove`.

Also this statement

```
strcat(input, end);
```

can overwrite memory outside the original array.

You should allocate a new character array within the function that is gretaer by 3 than the length of the original string and build in it
a new string.

if to use a variable length array to store the converted string then the function can look the following way as shown in the demonstration program below

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void pigLatinConsonant( const char *s ) 
{
    const char end[] = "ay";

    size_t length = strlen( s );

    char pig_latin[length + sizeof( end )];

    size_t i = 0;

    while (i != length && strchr( "aeiou", s[i] ) == NULL ) ++i;

    if (i == length)
    {
        strcpy( pig_latin, s );
    }
    else
    {
        strcpy( pig_latin, s + i );
        strncat( pig_latin, s, i );
        pig_latin[length] = '\0';
    }

    strcat( pig_latin, end );

    printf( "Translated word: %s\n", pig_latin );
}

int main( void )
{
    pigLatinConsonant( "pig" );
}
```

The program output is

```
Translated word: igpay
```

Comment: We havent learned about memmove so i dont think we can do that.. but I found the error, it is with the strncat, It will keep saying ay. How do i fix this?

Comment: @TanyaKumari I do not see where you are using strncat.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I meant to say strcat(input, end) is where the problem is

Comment: This solution works for a single word, not an entire sentence. There are other problems with the OP's code (as you mention) but the immediate issue is parsing individual words from the input string.

Comment: @B.Pantalone Her function is called for each word: pigLatinConsonant(token);.  She does not try to pass to the function a whole sentence.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `token` is a pointer into your original input string, and that string is modified with every call to `pigLatinConsonant(token)`. The function `strtok()` expects this string not to change.

Instead of copying the `sentence` into `sentence_copy`, copy `token` into a temporary `word` string and pass that into `pigLatinConsonant(word)`.

Answer (score 0):

From the man page for `strcpy()`:
"*Caveat**: The strings src and dst may not overlap.*"
So, using `strcpy()` to *shift left* the right-portion of the string causes UB.

(In some implementations, `strcpy()` begins copying with the `'\0'` as this can execute faster.)
It pays to make oneself *very* acquainted with the man pages...

---

Below shows how to search for the first vowel using a proven Standard Library function, and how to output regions of strings ( more information gleaned by careful study of the man page for `printf()`.) This version includes a hyphen to highlight the expected syllabification.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void piggish( char *cp ) {
    size_t vowel1 = strcspn( cp, "aeiou" ); // lowercase only
    if( vowel1 == 0 )
        printf( "%s-ay ", cp );
    else
        printf( "%s-%.*say ", cp + vowel1, vowel1, cp );
}

int main( void ) {
    char str[] = "when in rome do as the romans do\n";

    /* Notice the '\n' that fgets() leaves in the returned buffer
     * Notice the delimiters for strtok() eats that '\n'
     */

    puts( str );
    for( char *cp = str; ( cp = strtok( cp, " \n" ) ) != NULL; cp = NULL )
        piggish( cp );
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
when in rome do as the romans do
en-whay in-ay ome-ray o-day as-ay e-thay omans-ray o-day
```

Since segments of the received word are output, there's no need for buffers additional to those provided by `printf()`.

Comprehensive testing and increasing robustness is left as an exercise for the OP. For instance, dealing with words separated by a comma.

---

** "Caveat" is a Latin word. Perhaps expand this code to use a lexicon of commonly used Latin words to avoid *pig-ifying* those.